# MVC4 view showing validation summary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { style = "Width: 165px;", autocomplete = "off", maxlength = 100 })
            @Html.RequiredHint()
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This view is called from within another view like this:

```
    <div id="newcustomer-form">
        @{
            var dataDictAddress = new ViewDataDictionary();
            dataDictAddress.ModelState.Merge(ViewData.ModelState);
            dataDictAddress.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "NewCustomerDetails";
            @Html.Partial("AddEditCustomerDetails", Model.NewCustomerDetails, dataDictAddress)              
        }
    </div>
```

Everything is displayed correctly. However when the model gets validated (first name is missing), the error message is displayed in 2 places. The first is right next to the field (which is correct), and the second is displayed underneath the form.

I've checked to see if I'm using Html.ValidationSummary but I'm not.

Could there be another reason why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using masters for the view? And if yes, have you verified that there is no validation summary on them?

Comment: I have to assume that there is a validation summary in the other views, but the errors list appears only in my view.

Comment: Can you add the HTML markup rendered in the browser? That should give a clue as to what/why is being redered

Comment: That's quite a lot of code. What tags should I look for so I can add just those?

Comment: What is `@Html.RequiredHint()`?

Comment: @html.RequiredHint() displays a red star